# Cannot dispatch 2 actions together within function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Through my `Picker` component's `onValueChange` function, I set new value to state with `setState` afterwards, I'm calling `getOperators` function in order to dispatch 2 different actions from redux to save state to global store.

But I can't `dispatch` both `actions`. I'm going to share my code. I commented out the `writeProduct` action which causes issue. In this way, with only `checkTokenAndFetch` action, everything works fine. But, I need to somehow save my `selectedProductID` to redux, because I need this ID within other components.

Here is the `Picker` Component that I set `selectedProductID` State and call `getOperators` method.

```
<Picker  style={{width: width-40,  marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', borderColor: '#D3D3D3'}}
         selectedValue={this.state.selectedProductID}
         onValueChange={(id)=>this.setState({selectedProductID: id,visible: true},()=>this.getOperators())}
>
    {
        this.state.products.map((product, i) => {
            return(
                <Picker.Item label={product.name} value={product.id} key={i}/>
            );
        })
    }
</Picker>
```

Here is my `getOperators` method. I commented out the line where I dispatch `writeProduct` action, because this is where things get troubled.

```
getOperators(){
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    console.log("selectedProductID: ",this.state.selectedProductID);
    if(this.state.products.length>0){
        dispatch(authActions.writeProduct(this.state.selectedProductID));
        url = 'https://------------------?product=' + this.state.selectedProductID;
        requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
            }
        };

        dispatch(authActions.checkTokenAndFetch(url, requestOptions))
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("GET OPERATORS: ",data);
                this.setState({operators: data.data, selectedProduct:  data.data[0].productName,visible: false},()=>console.log("States After fetch: ",this.state));
            },
              (error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                })
    }
}
```

Here is the `writeProduct` action:

```
function writeProduct(id) {
    return {
        type: 'WRITE_PRODUCT',
        id
    }
}
```

Here is the reducer for `WRITE_PRODUCT`:

```
case 'WRITE_PRODUCT':
    console.log("WRITE PRODUCT ACTION: ", action);
    console.log("state: ",state);
    return {
        productID: action.id
    };
```

and here is the error I face when I trying to dispatch both Actions:

[image]

Because of '`cannot read property 'data' of undefined`' and everything works fine when I comment out `writeProduct` action, I believe maybe the issue is related with dispatching actions (a)synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things. In console you can see `console.log("GET OPERATORS: ",data);` is printing undefined. That means your api request is failing.

```
dispatch(authActions.getOperators(url, requestOptions))
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("GET OPERATORS: ",data);
            this.setState({operators: data.data, selectedProduct:  data.data[0].productName,visible: false},()=>console.log("States After fetch: ",this.state));
        },
          (error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            })
```

Here `data` is undefined and `data.data` is triggering cannot find data of undefined error. Then you dont have a catch block in promise chain.

May be it should be

```
dispatch(authActions.getOperators(url, requestOptions))
    .then((data) => {
        console.log("GET OPERATORS: ",data);
        this.setState({operators: data.data, selectedProduct:  data.data[0].productName,visible: false},()=>console.log("States After fetch: ",this.state));
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
```

You can dispatch any no of actions from same method, synchronously or asynchronously, it doesn't matter.